# What hashing techniques to use when building a bloom filter in clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, hash, bloom-filter

I want to build a bloom filter in Clojure but I don't have much knowledge of all the hashing libraries that may be available to JVM based languages.

What should I use for the fastest (as opposed to most accurate) bloom map implementation in Clojure?

Comment: What type of data are your keys? Strings? Byte arrays? Integers? UUIDs?

Comment: I'm testing for membership against a set of strings

Comment: You could try repeatedly applying a mixing hash function to the built-in hash value reported by the `hash()` method on the string, e.g. http://www.cris.com/~Ttwang/tech/inthash.htm The generated values might correlate too strongly, which could make the bloom filter ineffective. An approach I've used in the past is to use a hash function with a very long result, such as SHA-256, and split the result into chunks. This might be too slow for your purposes. The simplest might just be to do a google search for 'string hash function' and implement a few of the results it gives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the fun thing about bloom filters is that to work effectively they need multiple hash functions.

Java Strings already have one hash function built in that you can use - [String.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) with returns a 32-bit integer hash. It's an OK hashcode for most purposes, and it's possible that this is sufficient: if you partition this into 2 separate 16-bit hashcodes for example then this might be good enough for your bloom filter to work. You will probably get a few collisions but that's fine - bloom filters are expected to have some collisions.

If not, you'll probably want to roll your own, in which case I'd recommend using [String.getChars()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20int%29) to access the raw char data, then use this to calculate multiple hashcodes.

Clojure code to get you started (just summing up the character values):

```
(let [s "Hello"
      n (count s)
      cs (char-array n)]
  (.getChars s 0 n cs 0)
  (areduce cs i v 0 (+ v (int (aget cs i)))))
=> 500
```

Note the use of Clojure's Java interop to call getChars, and the use of areduce to give you a very fast iteration over the character array.

You may also be interested in this Java bloom filter implementation I found on Github: https://github.com/MagnusS/Java-BloomFilter . The hashcode implementation looks OK at first glance but it uses a byte array which I think is a bit less efficient than using chars because of the need to deal with the character encoding overhead.

Comment: Having written a Bloom Filter in Java (question was about JVM and hashing algorithms), multiple hash functions are NOT needed. Indeed (see answer below), a good MumurHash is excellent for Bloom Filters because they are extremely fast and the minor increased incidence of collision is not really a factor since Bloom Filters inherently have a false-positive rate anyway. The data type in the Set is also not relevant since a best-practice for performance and to manage false-positive rates is to smooth out the bit-set distribution by hashing the input keys anyway.

Comment: @Darrell - well you need enough independently calculated *bits* that you can segment the result into multiple hash functions. That's what the answer below does - I would define that as "using multiple hash functions" :-)

Comment: The question was about "hashing libraries that may be available to JVM based languages" so the comment was in reference to those versus the 'number of hash buckets' that are used/calculated. I think the phrase 'hash function' implies a function or method (implementation) whereas the comment below states 'calculate the desired number of hashes'. Sorry for any confusion but hopefully this clarifies for new users as this is a pretty heavy computer science topic.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the Bloom Filter implementation in [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). This uses the very fast [MurmurHash3](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) algorithm and combines two hashes (or two portions of the same hash, since upgrading to MurmurHash3 instead of MurmurHash2) in different ways to calculate the desired number of hashes.

The combinatorial generation approach is described in [this paper](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~kirsch/pubs/bbbf/esa06.pdf)

and here's a snippet from the Cassandra sourcecode:

```
    long[] hash = MurmurHash.hash3_x64_128(b, b.position(), b.remaining(), 0L);
    long hash1 = hash[0];
    long hash2 = hash[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < hashCount; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = Math.abs((hash1 + (long)i * hash2) % max);
    }
```

See also [Bloomfilter and Cassandra = Why used and why hashed several times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849283/bloomfilter-and-cassandra-why-used-and-why-hashed-several-times)